# problem with threading JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, actionlistener

I'm trying to make so that when I press a button the program starts a method in a new thread.
The problem is that when I press the button the program freezes until the method is done running like i didn't use a thread at all. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks Morgan.

```
public Listeners()
{
  Calendar.ButtonAddReminder.addActionListener(new ButtonAddListener());
}

private class ButtonAddListener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      new Thread(Calendar.reminder.Reminderchecker(Calendar.reminder.addReminder(date, str))) .start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From that, it looks like something in `Calendar.reminder.addReminder()` or `Calendar.reminder.Reminderchecker()` is taking some time and locking up the UI since that's what's happening in the EDT.

**Edit:** Oh, I see. You're not doing what you think you're doing. You're executing `Reminderchecker` in the current thread. The `Runnable` returned by that method is what's getting executed in the new thread. To run `Reminderchecker` in a thread, do something like:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Calendar.reminder.Reminderchecker(...);
    }
}).start();
```

Better: Don't spawn your own random threads like that. Use an organized concurrency strategy such as provided by an [`ExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). The [`Executors`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class lets you easily create several that cover common uses.

Still better: Check out the [SwingWorker](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/swingworker/) and it [API docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

Comment: Yes, Reminderchecker is taking time to run, thats why I want it to run in a new thread without locking up the system. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that all this happens in the new thread:

```
Calendar.reminder.Reminderchecker(Calendar.reminder.addReminder(date, str ))
```

At the moment

```
Calendar.reminder.addReminder(date, str )
```

and

```
Calendar.reminder.Reminderchecker()
```

are called on the Event Dispatching Thread before the new `Thread` is constructed and started.

The simplest way to correct this is to create a new `Runnable` object that carries out all of these steps, and then pass that to the new thread. I guess the returned object from Reminderchecker() is itself a `Runnable`, in which case you need something like this:

```
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Runnable r = Calendar.reminder.Reminderchecker(Calendar.reminder.addReminder(date, str ));
        r.run();
    };
new Thread(task).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `Calendar` class implements `Runnable` or extends `Thread` you should not call `Calendar.reminder.Reminderchecker(Calendar.reminder.addReminder(date, str ))` before starting the new Thread as this calls the `run()` method of the new thread.

Instead do something like that:

```
public class Calendar implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        this.reminder.Reminderchecker(Calendar.reminder.addReminder(date, str ));
    }    
}
```